# Complex equality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I don't understand where does this equality come from: $$\arctan \Bigl (\frac {\sin x} {\cos x +3}\Bigl)= \mathrm {Im} \log (i\sin x + \cos x +3).$$ I guess it's linked to the more famous equality relating $\arctan $ and complex logarithm, however I still don't see the point. Thanks for any explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complex logarithm is not uniquely defined so the statement is not correct. However one value of the imaginary part of $log (a+ib)$ is $\arctan (\frac  b a)$ so one value of RHS equals LHS in your equation.